# Are VueJS Boolean Props Similar to Boolean Parameters and If So, How to Eliminate Them?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, react-props

This question mainly asks about Vue, but is also applicable to various other frameworks such as React.

In programming, boolean parameters for functions are usually considered to be a code smell and a bad choice of design as they create unnecessary branching. In turn, the maintenance cost increases and cleanliness of the code declines significantly.

In VueJS, are boolean props for components similar to using boolean parameters for functions? Does using boolean props also create unnecessary branching in component structures and make it harder to maintain?

I can't think of a great example, so here's one that seems good enough.

For example, if I have a prop called `userNeedsToSignUp` and then design a hypothetical authentication page like so:

```
<template>
    <user-greeting-sign-up v-if="userNeedsToSignUp"/>
    <user-greeting-login v-else/>

    <form :action="userNeedsToSignUp ? '/sign-up' : '/login'" :method="userNeedsToSignUp ? 'post' : 'patch'">
        <template v-if="userNeedsToSignUp">
          <new-username-input-box/>
          <new-email-input-box/>
          <new-password-input-box/>
        </template>

        <template v-else>
          <existing-username-input-box/>
          <existing-email-input-box/>
          <existing-password-input-box/>
        </template>
    </form>

    <p v-if="userNeedsToSignUp">
        Have an account? <a>Sign in</a>
    </p>
    <p v-else>
        Need an account? <a>Create</a>
    </p>
</template>
```

As you can see, this creates a ton of branching inside the component structure. Therefore, this is probably a code smell and needs to be eliminated. What would be a better design choice for this particular scenario? Or, am I overthinking this and boolean props are just fine?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce branching and `v-if` usage, you can use [dynamic components](https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/).

For example, your forms could be dynamic components.  That said, I think there's plenty of cases where displaying different things based on a boolean value in a `v-if` is just fine.

You might also want to look into [Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) and its [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) feature.